# How to use the withCriteria results in a new withCriteria query in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-controller, gorm-mongodb

Consider the first query:

```
def books =  Book.withCriteria {
   eq("category", "fiction")
}
```

How can I use the result of this query in the next query to get all the authors who wrote these books?

I tried:

```
def authors = Author.withCriteria {
  'in'("books", books)
}
```

but this is not working. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just query the association directly?

```
def authors = Author.withCriteria {
  books {
    eq("category", "fiction")
  }
}
```

Comment: No because mongoDB does not support join operation. Any other idea?